# How to add METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable to Nginx with Passenger on CentOS 7?

Tags: meteor, nginx, passenger, centos7

I deployed my meteor app following [these](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/el7/deploy_app.html) instructions for CentOS 7 with Passenger and Nginx.

I've installed Passenger version 5.0.28 and Nginx 1.10 and I can start the service just fine.

but when I try to add:

```
passenger_env_var METEOR_SETTINGS '{ "public": { "ga": { "id": "UA-XXXXX-X" } } }';
```

to my etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf, the app could not start after restarting Nginx.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding white spaces to the JSON-string in the beginning and the end. So it looks like this:

```
passenger_env_var METEOR_SETTINGS ' { "public": { "ga": { "id": "UA-XXXXX-X" } } } ';
```